# PXUnboundDefault Not working

Tags: acumatica

The following is not working:

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{
    [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(Search<INItemStats.lastCost, Where<INItemStats.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>))]
    [PXDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Cost", Enabled = false, Visible = true, IsReadOnly = true)]
    public virtual Decimal? UsrLastCost { get; set; }
```

I have basically the same query running correctly in another customization.

Previously the query was in an event handler and I could see the SQL being executed by running the request profiler. After moving the query to an attributre, the query does not show up in the request profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the INItemStatus DAC it contains 2 keys (InventoryID and SiteID). When adding the siteid to the query I was able to return results.

Using this:

```
[PXUnboundDefault(typeof(Search<INItemStats.lastCost, 
    Where<INItemStats.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOLine.inventoryID>>, 
        And<INItemStats.siteID, Equal<Current<SOLine.siteID>>>>>), 
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Cost", Enabled = false)]
public virtual Decimal? ItemSiteLastCost { get; set; }
```

Returned the following:

[image]